# cannot remove defaultConfigurationName = Release from .pbxproj file

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS project,

```
defaultConfigurationName = Release;
```

is being added automatically in project.pbxproj file. I can't apply my previous stashed changes and i don't want to commit with this change either.
Whenever i discard this change, Xcode automatically add this line within seconds.
Please share your solution method if you resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can close Xcode, do all the needed stuff with the stash, commit, and then open Xcode again.

Why wouldn't you want that default configuration line though?

Xcode project files are notoriously difficult to merge. If you have specific policies about how often and for what reasons the project file should be changed, or you have lots of people working on the project and have constant merges and rebases, you may want to look in project file generators such as GYP or CMake. These usually have a more VCS-friendly format of files. But they add complexity to your pipeline, so consider this advice with caution.